# How can I auto-modify an image?

Tags: autogen

The question I am asking is a little bit abstract, so I will try to make it more clear. There are websites where you sign up and get a signature in the format of an image. It has a general format, say a few boxes that are empty, and a logo in the middle. Now, say you gain the "Overachiever" badge, which looks like a pen. You signature is then updated, automatically, to include that pen badge in one of the blank boxes. I am completely clueless as to how to do this, and in what language to do this is, so can anyone help? I have been thinking about PHP as an option, but I do not know if that would work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with PHP (imagecreate) and for the updates in your images you can use cronjobs.

Answer (score 0):

Is this for a forum? Depending on the platform, I know some hosts already have "addon's" that provide similar functionality to what you're after. (Karma addons etc.)

Maybe one of these will help? phpBB has some stuff like that. 
https://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?t=2147118

http://www.concrete5.org/

Answer (score 0):

If you can execute an external process, you can do this using Image Magick.